# How to get text?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Example:

```
<div class=" col-md-8">
   <strong>1.</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Every quadratic 
   polynomial 
 can have at most
 </div>
  <div class=" col-md-
   8">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(a) If 
   b<sup>2</sup> – 4ac is a perfect square, the roots are rational.
   </div>
```

How to use find_all method to get text of div which contains strong tag only?

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: for b in mcq.find_all('div',class_=" col-md-8")

Comment: you should include a minimal version of the code that you tried and that didn't work in your answer, it is greatly appreciated and makes helping you much easier. More on that: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: To clarify "div which contains strong tag only": Do you mean divs with nothing but a strong tag, or _only_ divs that contain a strong tag?

Answer (score 0):

By upgrading a little bit what you made :

```
results = []
for b in mcq.find_all('div',class_=" col-md-8"): #here you find all the div of the correct class
    if b and b.find_all("strong"): # then you check if there is a "strong" tag inside 
        results.append(b) # if yes => append it to the final list
```

Comment: I see that this is probably written as multiple lines for better commentability, but this might be even more elegant with a list comprehension.

Comment: you're right @D.Everhard it is (too) long on purpose ;)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go. Although I've used the class name from your provided content, they are not to rely on as they seem to generate dynamically.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_content='''
<div class=" col-md-8">
        <strong>1.</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Every quadratic 
        polynomial 
        can have at most
    </div>
    <div class=" col-md-
        8">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(a) If 
        b<sup>2</sup> – 4ac is a perfect square, the roots are rational.
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content,"lxml")
for items in soup.find_all("div",class_="col-md-8")[0].find_all("strong"):
    core_text = ' '.join([item.strip() for item in items.next_sibling.split()])
    print(core_text)
```

Output:

```
Every quadratic polynomial can have at most
```